# ImageSource binding 64bit vs 32bit

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

i have a problem in imagesource binding, this is the situation:

in my window i have a button:

```
<Button Background="{DynamicResource backColorButton}"/ >
```

the backColorButton is defined in my Style.xaml:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="backColorButton" Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding Path=BackgroundButtonImage}"></ImageBrush>
```

the BackgroundButtonImage is defined in the viewmodel:

```
public string BackgroundButtonImage
    {
        get
        {
          return (MyWorkPath + @"\Img\btnbkg.jpg");
        }
    }
```

Now the problem:
if i run my code on win7 sp1 64bit i have no problem: the button has the image in the background; but if i run my code on win7 sp1 32bit the button has a transparent background, the image is not loaded.

any idea?

thanks a lot

p.s: this is my first question here, so excuse me if there are problems on form or explain.

Comment: Are you sure you have image btnbkg.jpg in path: "MyWorkkPath" + @"\Img\" on your 32 bit machine?  64-bit vs 32-bit should have no difference in this case.  The behavior would suggest to me that the file is missing from your 32-bit machine.